# Sphinx hangs when attempting to use amxmath capabilities

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, equation, restructuredtext

I want to define a matrix in a math block in a ReST file like this;

```
.. math::

    \[\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1\\ a_2 & b_2\end{bmatrix}\]
```

In my conf.py I defined a preamble in order to include the LaTeX package amsmath

```
latex_elements = {
# Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
'preamble': r'''
\usepackage{amsmath}
'''
}
```

However when I try and compile my document using Sphinx, it gets to the document and hangs there permanently

```
writing output... [ 97%] theory_and_methodology
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't do that unneeded extra preamble thing, by default, for LaTeX output Sphinx does `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}` already. For HTML output with MathJax, what is in Sphinx LaTeX config is totally irrelevant. The problem was with the `\[...\]`. They are tacit, or use [nowrap](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/math.html?highlight=math#directive-math) option.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The LaTeX compiler didn't like the `\[` in the source. It was unnecessary, so when I removed it the output worked.